# Full screen CSS with minimum size

Tags: html, css

I have created a layout in CSS/HTML with the following structure:

[image: structure]

Navigation in the footer scrolls the content horizontally to show two different screens. The screen content is fixed height and vertically centered and the layout always fills the entire window.

Because my content has a fixed height, I need the browser to display a vertical scrollbar when the window reaches a certain height.

I also have a couple of `position:fixed` `<canvas>` overlays that get cropped by the `<html>` and `<body>` elements which are set to `height:100%; width:100%`.

I hoped that by setting `min-height:700px` on the `<body>` selector I could get a scrollbar to appear when the window got too short. This doesn't seem to be work.

How can I make this website generally full-screen but scroll when below a minimum size threshold?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that should effectively make sure the `body` is always at least 700px. However, `position: fixed` will still anchor them to the bottom of the viewport, so you will essentially be only scrolling the background. I believe you want the header/footer bars to stick to the top and bottom, so you can always see the full content between them?

So, does something like this fiddle behave more like what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/jblasco/qPB9k/8/

It uses a wrapper `div` that does the `min-height`, and uses absolutely positioned bars instead.

Comment: It's more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jblasco/qPB9k/8/ - but there's something different in my actual code that I need to figure out exactly why it's a different problem...

Comment: Could post some of your relevant HTML/CSS, or make a fiddle with what you have?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `overflow-x: auto;`

It will try to put a horizontal scroll bar once the content exceeded the size of its container.